# Restart wurstmeister/kafka-docker after server.properties changes due to ssl config

Tags: docker, ssl, apache-kafka

According to the docs, SSL config of a wurstmeister/kafka-docker is to be done in `server.properties` file, as follow:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://host.name:port,SSL://host.name:port
# The following is only needed if the value is different from ``listeners``, but it should contain
# the same security protocols as ``listeners``
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://host.name:port,SSL://host.name:port
```

and

```
ssl.keystore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
```

Source: https://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/kafka/ssl.html#configuring-kafka-brokers

I also followed the rest of the docs, so I also have the SSL and port 9093 configured:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSL://:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093
```

After I've done that, I have tried to stop and start the server again:

```
docker stop wurstmeister_kafka_1
docker start wurstmeister_kafka_1
```

and also

```
docker restart wurstmeister_kafka_1
```

But when I inspect with `docker ps`, I do not see port 9093 being bound:

```
λ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
                  NAMES
b6c5685414ec        wurstmeister/kafka:latest       "start-kafka.sh"         3 days ago          Up 6 minutes        0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp
                  wurstmeister_kafka_1
ded10e44873a        wurstmeister/zookeeper:latest   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   3 days ago          Up 3 days           22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp   wurstmeister_zookeeper_1
```

and the following command `openssl s_client -debug -connect localhost:9093 -tls1` said errors:

```
λ openssl s_client -debug -connect localhost:9093 -tls1
20024:error:0200274D:system library:connect:reason(1869):../openssl-1.1.1a/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
20024:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../openssl-1.1.1a/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
20024:error:0200274D:system library:connect:reason(1869):../openssl-1.1.1a/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
20024:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../openssl-1.1.1a/crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=0
```

How can I restart the docker so that changes in `server.properties` takes effect? If that's not the right approach, then what is?

Answer (score 1):

Docker doesn't preserve file changes within the image.

You either have to volume mount your own `server.properties` over the one in the container, or see if the environment variables allow you to update the configuration during the startup of the image (similar to the `confluentinc/kafka` image)

Comment: There is an environment variable, but its value points to a path and file in the file system. At the time of docker-compose up, this path and file do not exist yet, so that will throw an error. Also, I'm not trying to preserve like you said, just try to configure and restart

Comment: If you volume mounted the files, they would exist, though. You will need to generate the keys outside of the container

Comment: Thanks. Volume mounted which works. Environment variables which points to the path of the server keystore file and its password are passed.The problem with Kafka SSL remains, which I believe is outside the scope of Docker at this point.